# How many vertical field details can I have in a Java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, border-layout

I am aware of the NORTH, CENTER and SOUTH field details for setting a component (e.g. BorderLayout) to either the top, middle or bottom respectively, however, I was wondering if it's possible to have more than three components and if so, how would I go about doing this with additional field details.

Currently, I have the following.

> North - BorderLayout
>
> Center - GridLayout
>
> South - GridBagLayout

I am wanting to add an additional GridBagLayout to the bottom of the program (either below or above existing GridBagLayout). How would I go about adding an additional layout so that it does not interfere with and merge with the current SOUTH area?

Code:

```
public class boggleView extends JFrame {    
    public  boggleView(){
        super("Boggle");
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        
        JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel southPanelBottom = new JPanel();
        
        // North Panel
        getContentPane().add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JLabel gameBoardTitle = new JLabel("<html><font size = 5>Game Board</font></html>");
        northPanel.add(gameBoardTitle);
        
        // Middle Panel
        getContentPane().add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        middlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
        for(int button=0 ; button<16 ; button++){
            JButton diceButton = new JButton(String.valueOf("<html><font size = 10>E</font></html>"));
            diceButton.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            diceButton.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            diceButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            middlePanel.add(diceButton);
        }
        
        // South Panel        
        southPanel.setLayout (new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,0,10);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        Border wordBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);
        Border textFieldBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 2);
        JButton button;
        
        JLabel textField = new JLabel("");
        textField.setBorder(textFieldBorder);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 8;
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,35));
        southPanel.add(textField, c);
        
        button = new JButton("Submit");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        button.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 35));
        southPanel.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Cancel");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        button.setBackground(Color.RED);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 35));
        southPanel.add(button, c);
        
        button = new JButton("Restart");
        c.gridx = 4;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 35));
        southPanel.add(button, c);
        
        button = new JButton("Info");
        c.gridx = 6;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        button.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 35));
        southPanel.add(button, c);
        
        JLabel wordListTitle = new JLabel("<html><font size = 5>Recent Words</font></html>");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,5,0,0);
        southPanel.add(wordListTitle, c);
        
        
        // Bottom South Panel
        southPanelBottom.setLayout (new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints d = new GridBagConstraints();
        d.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        d.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        
        JLabel word  = new JLabel("<html><font size = 5>HAT</font></html>");
        word.setBorder(wordBorder);
        d.gridx = 0;
        d.gridy = 3;
        d.gridwidth = 2;
        southPanelBottom.add(word, d);
        
        JLabel word2 = new JLabel("<html><font size = 5>1</font></html>");
        word2.setBorder(wordBorder);
        d.gridx = 2;
        d.gridy = 3;
        d.gridwidth = 1;
        southPanelBottom.add(word2, d);
        
        getContentPane().add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use a new helper Panel with layout Borderlayout.

put your new GridBagLayout panel to this new helper Panel's South and put the existing GridBagLayout panel (currently at SOUTH) this panel's North.

then put this new helper Panel to SOUTH replacing old GridBagLayout panel.

```
    JPanel southHelperPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    southHelperPanel.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    southHelperPanel.add(southPanelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

    getContentPane().add(southHelperPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I have added code to the post. Bottom South Panel (southPanelBottom) is the new panel I am trying to add. And southPanel is the current SOUTH panel. How would I go about making a 'helper panel'?

Comment: Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine layouts as you need them. Please have a look at the below example.. In this example, the main panel has a BorderLayout. In the different directions of this panel I'm adding new panels with other layouts.

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Test() {

        JPanel main = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel top = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JPanel center = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        main.add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        main.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        main.add(bottom, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        this.getContentPane().add(main);
        this.setSize(800, 500);
    }
}
```

You could also give your main panel a different layout (like GridBagLayout) if you need more "directions" in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

BorderLayout cannot itself do this; it can only lay out 3 things vertically. Switch the container (`window.getContentPane()`, presumably) to a different layout.

Something similar-ish to BorderLayout is to use `BoxLayout`; I'd need to know a little more about exactly what's in those subcomponents to be sure if it's the right replacement here.